# Empty list in jquery mobile

Tags: asp.net, list

I have created a list in JQuery mobile asp.net webform application.  Below is my code

```
 <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="g">
    <% foreach (string item in CustomerOrder())
     { %>
      <li><a href="#"><% item.ToString();%></a></li> 

    <% } %>

  </ul>
```

Where CustomerOrde is the public function on server side with List return type. I have placed breakpoint on this list and I can see it is being iterated and item is showing values, as expected.

But web page is showing empty list

[image: Empty List]

Where I am wrong?

**EDIT1**

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-theme="g">

      <li><a href="#"></a></li> 


      <li><a href="#"></a></li> 


      <li><a href="#"></a></li> 


      <li><a href="#"></a></li> 


      <li><a href="#"></a></li> 


      <li><a href="#"></a></li> 


      <li><a href="#"></a></li> 


      <li><a href="#"></a></li> 


      <li><a href="#"></a></li> 


      <li><a href="#"></a></li> 


      <li><a href="#"></a></li> 


      <li><a href="#"></a></li> 


      <li><a href="#"></a></li> 


      <li><a href="#"></a></li> 


      <li><a href="#"></a></li> 


      <li><a href="#"></a></li> 


      <li><a href="#"></a></li> 


      <li><a href="#"></a></li> 


      <li><a href="#"></a></li> 


      <li><a href="#"></a></li> 


      <li><a href="#"></a></li> 


      <li><a href="#"></a></li> 


      <li><a href="#"></a></li> 


      <li><a href="#"></a></li> 


      <li><a href="#"></a></li> 


      <li><a href="#"></a></li> 


      <li><a href="#"></a></li> 


      <li><a href="#"></a></li> 


      <li><a href="#"></a></li> 


      <li><a href="#"></a></li> 


      <li><a href="#"></a></li> 


      <li><a href="#"></a></li> 


      <li><a href="#"></a></li> 


      <li><a href="#"></a></li> 


      <li><a href="#"></a></li> 


      <li><a href="#"></a></li> 


      <li><a href="#"></a></li> 


      <li><a href="#"></a></li> 


      <li><a href="#"></a></li> 


      <li><a href="#"></a></li> 


      <li><a href="#"></a></li> 


      <li><a href="#"></a></li> 


      <li><a href="#"></a></li> 


      <li><a href="#"></a></li> 


      <li><a href="#"></a></li> 


      <li><a href="#"></a></li> 


      <li><a href="#"></a></li> 


      <li><a href="#"></a></li> 



  </ul>
```

Comment: please post a snippet of the generated html

Comment: @splonk I have now updated the question with HTML content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You see empty elements (`<a href="#"></a>`) because you did not output the return value of `ToString`. Try:

```
<%= item.ToString() %>
```

I'd also recommend not using `ToString` but another custom method or property - `ToString` is usually meant for programmer debugging use.

Comment: It worked for me. except a minor change <%= item.ToString()%> . Thank you. :-)

Comment: @Chris - Thanks! I always miss that one... `:P`